# toElement only seems to work in Chrome, not IE or FF

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have the following Javascript, and it only works in Chrome, and I can't figure out why:

```
//makes appointments draggable
    $("._ts").sortable({
        connectWith: "._ts", 
        revert: "true",
        cancel: ".new_appt",

    stop: function(e){
        var element =  e.toElement; 
        var date = $(element).parents('.route_container').find('.date h2').html(); 
        var timeslot = $(element).parents('.timeslot').attr('id'); 
        var tAppt_id = $(element).attr('id'); 
        console.log("Date:."+date); 
        console.log("time:."+timeslot); 
        console.log("route:."+tAppt_id); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajaxurl, 
            data:{action: "update_appointments", date: date, timeslot: timeslot, appt_id: tAppt_id},
            success: function(response){
                if(response.type == "success"){
                    console.log("Update appointment worked."); 
                    console.log("Date:."+response.date); 
                    console.log("time:."+response.timeslot); 
                    console.log("route:."+response.timeslot); 



                    $(this).parents('.delete_appt').hide(); 
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

The problem is that the variables `date`, `timeslot`, & `tAppt_id` are returned as `undefined`. Again this works in Chrome; but, only in Chrome. DOES NOT work in IE or FF.

I have also tried using `e.currentTarget` and `e.relatedTarget` neither worked. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you using jQuery-UI Sortable. In this case you'll get jQuery [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object as first parameter to event handler. To get event target element you'll need to use [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property:

```
var element = e.target;
```

Comment: I just realized that The answer you gave me gets the origin element, how would I get the element where the item was dropped?

Comment: According to [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) it'll be `ui.item` from handlers second parameters `stop: function(e, ui){`.