# window.addEventListener("mousedown", function()) doesn't work on IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, addeventlistener

```
componentDidMount(){
 window.addEventListener("mousedown", this.pageClick)
}

pageClick = (e) => {
 console.log(e.toElement)
}
```

here `e.toElement` is returned `null` on IE11 and the same is working fine on Chrome and Firefox.
I know that `addEventListener` is now supported in IE11 so I am not sure why it is not working. If anyone have any possible solution please share.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467212/typeerror-param-toelement-is-undefined

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `toElement` is no longer supported by IE 11. I found some related threads and you can refer to: [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701972/toelement-only-seems-to-work-in-chrome-not-ie-or-ff), [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600174/event-toelement-in-ie8-and-firefox/26115308#26115308).

As a workaround, you can use `e.target` which works well in IE 11 and other browsers.

Ref link: [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)